# Why is it neccessary to add a PCL's nuget packages to the application project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget, portable-class-library

Say I have a Visual Studio 2015 solution with two projects, `MyApp` (.NET) and `MyLib` (Portable--targeting .NET 4.6 and UWP 10). It compiles and runs fine.

Then I add any NuGet package to `MyLib`--could be anything, but let's just pick *Rx-Main* just as an example. I add a simple line of code in a `MyLib` class that makes use of an Rx type.

Now `MyApp` will crash upon startup with a FileNotFoundException citing the nuget package dll. By adding the same NuGet package to `MyApp` solves the issue.

**Why is it necessary to add the NuGet package to the application project as well?**

If `MyLib` was a normal .NET project this would not be necessary.

**EDIT**
Some clarification is needed...

In a standard .NET class library project, all the NuGet packages show up as individual DLLs under *References*:

[image]

They each have a dozen properties that can be edited in the *Properties* window, including `Copy Local`:

[image]

In a PCL project, under *References*, the NuGet packages have no properties whatsoever, and no way to have them copied to the output directory.

[image]

[image]

There are at least two problems with this situation:

1. It only rears its ugly head at runtime (FileNotFoundException), not compile time.
2. Now every client of that PCL project is forced to deal with all the dependencies of that PCL, whereas before it was cleanly transparent.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280717/references-from-class-library-are-not-copied-to-running-project-bin-folder, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816769/dependent-dll-is-not-getting-copied-to-the-build-output-folder-in-visual-studio. The executing application will always need to be able to find the assemblies that your referenced projects reference (as soon as their types are to be used), whether those references are project references or assembly references (where the latter are managed by NuGet or not, does not matter).

Comment: @CodeCaster, why is this not a requirement for a standard .NET library project? I realize that for those, each DLL has its `Copy Local` property set to `true` by default... but how can the same be achieved for those blue-icon NuGet package references?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. At runtime, the runtime must be able to load all required assemblies. Whether those were packed in (dependencies of) NuGet packages does not matter.

Comment: Learn more about the crash such as exception message and call stack. That can tell.

Comment: @CodeCaster: please see EDIT

Comment: Hard to imagine this failure mode, tends to only go wrong when a library uses reflection.  MSBuild copies dependent DLLs but it will not complain when it can't find them.  Basic checks are verifying that the DLL(s) indeed got copied to the build directory of the PCL library project.  And running ildasm.exe and looking at the manifest for .assembly directives for the Nuget assemblies.  Troubleshoot by digging through the diagnostic MSBuild trace.

Comment: @HansPassant, no need to imagine; create a new VS solution, follow those basic steps, and you'll see what I'm describing (unless there's something screwed-up with my VS or NuGet installation)

Comment: Did you ever solve this?